# How to find number of items in a filtered subset in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, filter

I have a D3 dataset of country information, and I want to filter it so that when you select a certain country, it only shows you information for other countries in that region. It works fine, but I can't tell how many countries it filters, and I was wondering if anyone knew how to do that?

```
    var entering = selection
        .enter()
        .filter(function (d) {
          return (d.Region == selRegion);
        })
```

This is the portion of code I have so far. When I try to do entering.length it returns null (but otherwise graphs fine).

Comment: I believe you are looking for `entering.size()` ([docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_size))

Comment: Well, it could be a textbook for an older version of d3 - there are some substantial differences between v3 and v4.